# a problem in elementary number theory basis

Tags: elementary-number-theory

if $(a,b\in \Bbb Z )$ we have $a|b$ then for which $c\in \Bbb Z $ then $a+c|b+c$.
 (find all $c$ that denote this condition)

Comment: Have you done any experiments to get a feel for what kinds of answers you get? What happens when $a=1,b=5$? When $a=b$?

Comment: If $b=ka$, then $b+c=ka+c$. So if the condition holds, then there is $n$, with $na+nc=ka+c$, hence $(n-k)a=(1-n)c$, i.e. $c=(n-k)a/(1-n)$, and, for any $n$, $c$, as obtained this way, if an integer, does fulfill the requirements. therefore they are all.

Comment: Please describe the question in the title, so that one could decide whether this is interesting or not: it could improve readability of the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $b+c=d(a+c)$, then $b-a=(d-1)(a+c)$.
Therefore, we can find one value $c=k-a$ for every divisor $k$ of $b-a$.
Note that $b-a=0$ allows arbitrary $k$ and hence arbitrary $c\in\mathbb Z$. In all other cases there are only finitely many divisors of $b-a$, but don't forget that they are also allowed to be negative!

*Example:*
If $a=1$ and $b=5$, then $b-a=4$ has divisors $-4, -2, -1, 1, 2,$ and $ 4$ leading to $c\in\{k-a\mid k\in\mathbb Z, k|b-a\}=\{-5, -3, -2, 0, 1, 3\}$ as solution.